# Android find if rowID exists using Cursor?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, cursor, element

I am trying to determine if a certain row exists, when I am just looking for the first row I use

`Cursor_element.moveToFirst()` which returns a boolean

but for other rows, what function would I use? I am trying

`Cursor_element.moveToPosition(7)`

where I am guessing that the `moveToPosition` counts cells? but I don't know

what is the best way to determine if a row exists?

Comment: Yes, but the SQL statements return void. I need one of the prebuilt android sqlite wrapper functions that returns a bool or 0, 1

Comment: My only point was if you can restrict your query to the row that interests you, then you won't have to jump <x> rows ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
int getCount()
```

> Returns the numbers of rows in the cursor.

Reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteCursor.html#getCount%28%29

```
if (i<Cursor_element.getCount())
  Cursor_element.moveToPosition(i);
```